# how to change string value in react.js

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I new to react and I'm having a hard time on how to change the title when I click the button.any help would be really appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './style.css';
class Layout extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            name:"Title",
        };
    }

    func() {
        this.setState({name: "NewTitle"});
    }

    render() {
        // setTimeout(()=>{
        //     this.setState({name: "John"});
        // },2000)

        return (
            <div className = "layout">
                <h2>{this.state.name}</h2>
                <p>{this.props.val}</p>
                <input onClick = {this.func} type = "submit" value = "Done"/><br/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing one part, binding of `func` method, put this line in the constructor: `this.func=this.func.bind(this)`, Check this [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/nt6xLmzg/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main part you are missing is the context `this`.

As `this` has got function scope the function you are calling i.e.,

```
onClick = {this.func}
```

has lost it's context.

So there are two ways to achieve this.

1) Using the fat arrow function

Fat arrow function has lexical scope. It passes the `this` context of the class into the function you declare.

```
class Layout extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            name:"Title",
        };
    }

    func = () => {
        this.setState({name: "NewTitle"});
    }

    render() {
        // setTimeout(()=>{
        //     this.setState({name: "John"});
        // },2000)

        return (
            <div className = "layout">
                <h2>{this.state.name}</h2>
                <p>{this.props.val}</p>
                <input onClick = {this.func} type = "submit" value = "Done"/><br/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

2) Binding the context i.e., pass the `this` context to the function you call

```
class Layout extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.func=this.func.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            name:"Title",
        };
    }

    func(){
        this.setState({name: "NewTitle"});
    }

    render() {
        // setTimeout(()=>{
        //     this.setState({name: "John"});
        // },2000)

        return (
            <div className = "layout">
                <h2>{this.state.name}</h2>
                <p>{this.props.val}</p>
                <input onClick = {this.func} type = "submit" value = "Done"/><br/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Commented code for better understanding

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Layout extends Component {
  // missing props argument 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // better naming. tell the intent with the state name
    this.state = {
      title: "Default Title",
    };
  }


  updateTitle = (e) => {
    // it prevents the default behaviour of a form which is to submit
    e.preventDefault();
    // refs are probably outdated. task for you to improve it :)
    const newTitle = this.refs['wordfield'].value;
    this.setState({ title: newTitle });
    this.refs['wordfield'].value = "";
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="layout">
        <h2>{this.state.title}</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.updateTitle}>
          <p>Enter the new title</p>
          <input type='text' ref='wordfield'/>
          <button type='submit'>Start!</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Layout
```